# What does "落地" in "政策落地" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean the policy is grounded,  getting nowhere, futile or scrapped?

And is it the same as 落地签证?

Comment: The reason for downvote?

Comment: The reason for downvote was the original question used a bad example (getting too political) , I removed it.

Comment: 落地 in 政策落地 means 落地生根.
A seed fell to the ground and began to take root.
It is the same as 落实/贯彻 here.
to carry out; to fulfill; to implement; to put into effect.

Answer (score 2):

> From this [article](http://news.xinhuanet.com/fortune/2017-06/07/c_1121099775.htm)
>
> *国家税务总局近日召开全国视频会议，部署贯彻落实国务院6项减税新政策，要求各级税务机关采取切实有效措施，确保减税政策**落地见效**。*

- Policies are decided at the top (by the law makers in the central government).
- '落地' means 'to land' or 'to touch down'
- '政策**落地**' means a Central government decided policy is passed down to the ground level (responsible agencies and local governments) for implementation
- 政策落地见效 means a policy is immediately effective upon implementation

> *And is it the same as 落地签证?*

No, they are not the same

[落地签证](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%90%BD%E5%9C%B0%E7%AD%BE%E8%AF%81) means 'visa on arrival '; '落地' means 'arrival' here

> *落地签证是指申请人不直接从所在国家取得前往其他国家的签证，而是持护照和该国有关机关发给的入境许可证明等抵达该国口岸后，再签发签证，落地签证通常是单边的*。

Answer (score 1):

政策落地
literally:
The policy has been **landed**.
figuratively:
The policy has been **in effect** / **carried out** / **implemented**.

落地政策
literally:
a **landed** policy
figuratively:
an **effective** / **operative** / **implemented** policy

The word **landed** here means that the policy is not only a proposal, a legal provision, a dead letter, or no news about it for a long time, but also implemented, performed immediately. It could be interpreted as **落**实到**地**方: **implemented** in some **place**.

落地签证
visa on arrival, visa on landing

Comment: What about 人头落地？

Comment: @NanningYouth it is the original meaning, **falling** to the **ground**, and then **landing**, and more meaning now, like: 落地扇 floor fan, 落地窗 French window, 落地签 landing visa, 落地政策 a fall-to-ground policy, or a real implemented policy.

Comment: 人头落地 means executing death sentence by beheading the criminal in ancient China

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to confirm whether this is a new definition coming out of China media or bureaucratic articles, or just a bad listening error (China media proof-reading qualities are pretty terrible nowaday)

In Mandarin, 落地 only carry 3 meaning

1. falls to the ground
2. From (ship) Walk to the ground
3. metaphor for giving birth (呱呱落地）

落地签证 will take the meaning of 2).

Historically, Chinese never use 落地 for anything that deal with policy.

So here is two possible speculation 
 1. It is a bad proof-reading
 2. It is possible abbreviation for “政策【落】实到【地】方政府”

The reason for the second possibility is because China local governments are infamous of not following central government policies, a political cultural issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here 落地 means, if I don't get it all wrong, the policy, or policies, is no longer words on paper only but has been carried out, performed, or implemented by some agency, or agencies, somehow some time to some extent somewhere on the mainland China. Other similar words are 落实.

Answer (score 0):

落地means landed,as 落地签证,get visa after landed.政策落地means the policy is being operating or working out